# MySQL stored procedure behaving unpredictably

Tags: mysql

Writing a stored procedure to parse names in format 'last first mid' and 'last first mid suffix' into a table.

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE parse_full_name(full_name TEXT)
  BEGIN
    SET @last_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(full_name, ' ', 1);
    SET @middle_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(full_name, ' ', -1);
    SET @first_name = SUBSTR(full_name, LOCATE(' ', full_name), LENGTH(full_name) - LENGTH(@middle_name) - LENGTH(@last_name));

    SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT ''', @last_name,''' as last_name, ''', @first_name,''' as first_name, ''', @middle_name,''' as middle_name;');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END;
```

---

```
CALL parse_full_name('last first middle');

>>>  last_name | first_name | middle_name
>>> -----------|------------|-------------
>>>  last      | first      | middle

CALL parse_full_name('last first middle suffix');

>>>  last_name | first_name   | middle_name
>>> -----------|--------------|-------------
>>>  last      | first middle | suffix
```

---

Does exactly what's expected. Now let's handle the suffix case:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE parse_full_name(full_name TEXT)
  BEGIN # assume full_name is 'last first middle' until proven not
    SET @last_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(full_name, ' ', 1);
    SET @middle_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(full_name, ' ', -1);
    SET @first_name = SUBSTR(full_name, LOCATE(' ', full_name), LENGTH(full_name) - LENGTH(@middle_name) - LENGTH(@last_name));

    # check if full_name is actually 'last first mid suffix'
    # if so then first_name will contain 'first middle'
    IF LOCATE(' ', @first_name) THEN # this if statement always evaluates to true
      SET @last_name = CONCAT(@last_name, ' ', @middle_name);
      SET @middle_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@first_name, ' ', -1); # mysql seems to skip this line of code
      SET @first_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@first_name, ' ', 1);   # this line too
    END IF;

    SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT ''', @last_name,''' as last_name, ''', @first_name,''' as first_name, ''', @middle_name,''' as middle_name;');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END;
```

---

Results:

```
CALL parse_full_name('last first middle jr');
```

Expecting:

```
>>>  last_name | first_name | middle_name
>>> -----------|------------|-------------
>>>  last jr   | first      | middle
```

But get:

```
>>>  last_name | first_name | middle_name
>>> -----------|------------|-------------
>>>  last jr   |            |
```

and even better:

```
CALL parse_full_name('last first middle');

>>>  last_name   | first_name | middle_name
>>> -------------|------------|-------------
>>>  last middle |            |
```

---

So, where's the problem? I'm not a MySQL pro, but everything looks logically and intuitively correct.

Comment: First, don't use prepared statements here: without careful sanitisation of the parameters provided to the sproc, you're just opening yourself to risks of SQL injection and quoting bugs (for example, just try calling your procedure with `Paddy O'Byrne` as the parameter); and you don't need to use prepared statements anyway, since `SELECT @last_name AS last_name, ...` would yield the same result just fine.  Second, don't put business logic like this into the database—it belongs in your application.  Third, splitting everyone's name in this way is guaranteed to lead to erroneous results.

Comment: @eggyal Thanks, I see that it's leading to erroneous results. Is there a reason why `LOCATE(' ', @foo)` would be true for @foo = 'nospaces'? Or `SET @foo = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@bar, ' ', -1);` would assign empty string to @foo for @bar = 'one space'?

Answer (score 1):

Rookie mistake. Just had to trim the strings.

```
SET @len_first_name = LENGTH(full_name) - LENGTH(@middle_name) - LENGTH(@last_name));
SET @first_name = SUBSTR(full_name, LOCATE(' ', full_name), @len_first_name);
```

`@len_first_name` grabs the space between first and middle, so @first_name ends up returning `' first middle'`, which would explain why `LOCATE(' ', @first_name)` was always returning true.

---

```
SET @last_name = TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(full_name, ' ', 1));
SET @middle_name = TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(full_name, ' ', -1));
SET @len_first_name = LENGTH(full_name) - LENGTH(@middle_name) - LENGTH(@last_name);
SET @first_name = TRIM(SUBSTR(full_name, LOCATE(' ', full_name), @len_first_name));
```

and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

The task is unsolvable.

- "Mary Jane" is a common first_name -- *not* first and middle.
- A lot of Brits have a 2-word last names.
- I have seen "Dear Mr. Iii" and "Dear Mr. Smith Iii".  Technically "III" should be all caps, and preceded by a comma.
- Will you mess up the case? (McDonald -> Mcdonald?) or apostrophe (O'Henry).
- Some people have more than one middle_name.

You are setting yourself up to irritate people with names that don't follow the simplistic parsing rules.

Why do you need to parse the name?  Can't you simply store and regurgitate the full_name?

Comment: Updating a bunch of old archived tables to new table format. Old tables use full_name, new tables use first/last. We have very few branch cases and the logic to handle them is easy, if first_name = '' then name would be 'first last', if suffix is not in ('jr', 'sr', 'ii', 'iii', etc) then we dump the whole name into last_name because it's usually an law firm, correctional facility, or other institution. Special characters don't exist, this isn't user-facing data. I don't know why we store first and last name separately, we have dozens of name parsers, it's just how it needs to be done.

Comment: This 'first last mid suff' case is by far the most popular, and we have ~5-6 implementations of it spread across 3 different languages. We're getting sick of rewriting it, so short of setting up a name parsing microservice we'd like to just plug the simple logic into a stored procedure and put it to rest once and for all.